# Optimising Keras CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am having trouble increasing accuracy and reducing loss in my CNN.

Here are some initial parameters:

```py
batch_size  = 32
image_shape = 150 # Sizes input to 150x150
EPOCHS      = 250
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 7
IMAGES_IN_CLASS_FOLDERS > 100
```

I have the training and validation set as the same images but I pre process the training images so that the validation images are not the same thus:

```py
# Image formatting - Preprocessing images into floating point tensors before being fed into the network
        # Generator for our training data       - Rescales the image, Flips Images Horizontally, Rotates it
        train_image_generator      = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, horizontal_flip=True, rotation_range=45)
        # Generator for our validation data     - Rescales the image
        validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
        # Applies scaling and resizing
        train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                   directory=training_Images,
                                                                   shuffle=True,
                                                                   target_size=(image_shape,image_shape), #(100,100)
                                                                   class_mode='categorical')
        val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                      directory=validate_Images,
                                                                      shuffle=True             ,
                                                                      target_size=(image_shape, image_shape),
                                                                      class_mode='categorical')
```

Further I have a Sequential model, which I have tried various parameters such as an input `CONV2D(32) -> CONV2D(64) -> CONV2D(128)` but I am currently testing this model with no success:

```py
# Defining our model
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            # Old Method #
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8 , (2,2) , activation='LeakyReLU', input_shape=(image_shape, image_shape, 3)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (2,2) , activation='LeakyReLU'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2,2) , activation='LeakyReLU'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(40, (2,2) , activation='LeakyReLU'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(56, (2,2) , activation='LeakyReLU'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2,2) , activation='LeakyReLU'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(96, (2,2) , activation='LeakyReLU'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (2,2), activation='LeakyReLU'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='softmax'),
            #tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
            #tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(120)
            # End Old Method #
            ])
```

I have tried various `CONV2D` layers, various activation methods. Here is the model.compile:

```py
        model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01),
                      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am using an `SGD Optimizer`, I have tried `ADAM` but with similar results. `Loss` is reduced overtime but it seems to reach a certain value range and stagnate with no increase in `Accuracy`.

model.fit:

```py
        history = model.fit(
            train_data_gen,
            steps_per_epoch= stepForEpoch,
            epochs=EPOCHS,
            validation_data=val_data_gen,
            validation_steps=stepForEpoch
        )
```

Can anyone offer some tips or point me in the right direction on how to increase the accuracy and reduce loss even further? Thank you!

*Image of Results*
[image]

*Final Update*
As of **06/23/2021** my model is improving significantly, not only with more EPOCHS but with more STEPS_PER_EPOCH:

[image]

[image]

Dividing the number of images like thus (IMAGES_IN_DATASET(20700) / BATCH_SIZE(32) = 677 STEPS_PER_EPOCH) and choosing 100 EPOCHS to test I am getting an increasing value for accuracy + 10% and an ever decreasing loss with an improvement in MSE.

```py
ACCURACY_INCREASE = %10
MSE_IMPROVEMENT   = -0.0004
ACCURACY_LOSS_IMPROVEMENT = -1.1
```

Thank you to users
@Reda El Hail
@Dr. Snoopy

Comment: In the last layer `tf.keras.layers.Dense(120)` you did not specify activation function. If you are working on a classification task set it to softmax

Comment: @RedaElHail does the previous dense layer not pass along the activation type to the foremost one? If so my apologies for such an oversight.

*edit* and further should i remove the softmax from the previous dense layer?

Comment: The activation function is set only for one layer and does not pass along to the foremost one. So I suggest to set the last layer to `softmax` and the previous one to `LeakyReLU `as the other layers.

Comment: @RedaElHail Thank you for the suggestion, I am getting significantly lower loss on each iteration. Do you see any problems with how my CONV2D layers are set up or do you think I should scrap that and start back off with 32,64,128 Kernel layers?

Comment: Using softmax in hidden layers makes no sense, only use it in the output layer.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you for tip. Question regarding this model in particular the metrics used to determine how well it is preforming, would a better metric be MSE or should I stick to accuracy

Comment: @HRD1997BFBE , the architecture of the model looks fine. But I would suggest you to start with a smaller model than the one used an see the results. Then deepen your model  bit by bit by adding more layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the discussion in comments, the error comes from the last layer where an activation function is not set `tf.keras.layers.Dense(120)`.

For a classification task, it should be `tf.keras.layers.Dense(120, activation = 'softmax')`.

As [@Snoopy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/dr-snoopy) announced: there is no sense to use `softmax` in hidden layers. It should be only used in the output layer.